# switching C compiler causes: Error Initializer cannot be specified for a flexible array member

Tags: compiler-construction

I am trying to convert our code from one IDE to be used in a different one.  The current one uses gcc which allows for this structure to be initialized from a variable array.  The new tool does not use gcc gives me an error "Initializer cannot be specified for a flexible array member".  So can someone help me understand how to set this up?  Should I set up a blank array of variable size and then somewhere assign the #define array as seen below?

Here would be an example of the code…(this is current implementation current IDE)

In one header file that is Build switchable so we can build this on different hardware platforms we have the following #define

```
#define GPIOS  \ 
          /*     BANK, PIN, SPD,  MODE,…  */
      GPIOINIT(   A,   0,   2,   AIN,  …) \
      GPIOINIT(   A,   1,   2,   AIN,  …) \
      GPIOINTINIT(A,   2,   2,   AIN,  …) \
      .
      .
      .
```

Then in a different header file that is used in all builds we have

```
  PLATFORM_CONFIG_T g_platformConfig = {
          .name = {PLATFORM_NAME},

          (bunch of other stuff),

         .allGpios = {
                     GPIOS /* here I get the error */
         },
   };
```

So I am thinking I can make the error line a variable array and assign to it later in some other way?  The problem is the actual array "GPIO" is of different types and pin orders on different designs are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing flexible array members with an aggregate is a gcc extension. The good news is that since you are allocating the `g_platformConfig` statically, you do not need that member to be a flexible array: you can go for a fixed-size array instead.

It is very likely that somewhere in your code you have a definition of the constant that says how many items there are in the `GPIOS` array (otherwise, you'd need to rely on a "sentinel" value of sorts, similar to null terminator of C strings, to know where legitimate `GPIOS` values end). If you have that constant already, modify the definition of `allGpios` to be

```
gpoinit_t allGpios[GPIO_COUNT]; // regular array
```

instead of

```
gpoinit_t allGpios[]; // flexible array
```

With this change in place, your code should compile correctly.

If you do not have a `GPIO_COUNT` constant, consider either adding one, or introducing a `MAX_GPIO` value limiting the number of items in `allGpios`. Either way, converting the array to a non-flexible one will fix the error.

Comment: We have different hardware configurations.  I am not certain that the number is consistent across platforms.  I may be able to allocate for the largest one and waste the space otherwise but that may cause other problems when looping through IO's...  Since I am just trying to get this to work for one version for now I will try a fixed array but I don't think this solves my problem.  Furthermore if I can't do this it may prevent us from using this IDE…or maybe we have to rearrange the code so this is also a product specific struct. - Thanks though

Comment: @user1054210 If you have `GPIOS` conditionally defined based on the platform, you could put a definition of `GPIO_COUNT` into the same conditional block. This would let you avoid the error with very little change.

Comment: Also I may not have made it clear but the define GPIO is an array of inconsistent arrays.  GPIOINTINIT is larger than GPIOINIT.  The #define GPIO has many included lines as shown above and they are inconsistent from design to design.

Comment: yeah that is what I was thinking, lets try...Naw that didn't work but I think it is having a different problem so I did something wrong.   Thanks though.  I think I understand HOW to solve this I just need to get a few more things in line.  I believe the actual struct is a bit more complicated than I described and that is where I am having trouble.

Comment: To be clear yes...this does fix that error.  Fixing the size to a constant removes the error for using a variable.  I didn't want to add more unique stuff in the platform specific files but I will for this evaluation.  It still won't compile now because of something really stupid.  I will figure this out so thanks for the help.